# How to replace value of a key from a String

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like

> [txnAmt=47210, txnCrncy=INR, cardExpiryDate=20140430, cardHolderName=XX, cardNumber=143448709244301, cvv2=123]

I want to replace value corresponding to key cardNumber i.e., want to replace 143448709244301 or whatever value it be with 676767676767

How can I do that using Java?

Comment: I was thinking to use replace method of String but as the value is not always the same this won't work.

Comment: This is a basic regex. You should have a look at the documentation (for example [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). In this present state this question is a "write the code for me" question.

Comment: @SwarupSaha Read about regex, they are what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a regex replace with a lookbehind:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=cardNumber=)\\d+", "676767676767");
```

You can use a similar regex to grab the existing value first:

```
String value = str.replaceAll(".*cardNumber=(\\d+).*", "$1");
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to get the existing value first and then replace it with some other one. Any help on this

Comment: @SwarupSaha See my edit.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks shmosel. I am really weak in REGEX. That's why asked the question. And you helped me. Good people still exists :)